# React-Native component import issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React-Native.Following a Tutorial from You tube tried same thing in my code but facing strage issue.
I just imported "KeyboardAvaoidingView" from 'react-native' and replace the top "View" with "KeyboardAvoidingView" I'm getting error. If I roll back to "View" application start running.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {  
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  View,
  Image,

} from 'react-native';

import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

export default class Login extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
        <View style={styles.logContainer} >
             <Image style={styles.logo} 
                source={require("../images/yeti-logo.jpg")}
                />   
            <View style={styles.heading}>
              <Text style={styles.textHeading}>
                Hello World
              </Text>
            </View>
        </View>  
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <LoginForm />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#039be5',
  },
  logContainer: {
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex:1
  },
  logo:{
    width:300,
    height:200
  },
  heading:{
    backgroundColor: '#7cb342'
  },
  textHeading:{
    color:'#ffffff',
    width: 300,
    textAlign: 'center',

  },
  formContainer:{
  }
})
```

;

Error: 
[image]

LoginForm code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';


export default class LoginForm extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>                
        <TextInput             
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="username or email"
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          />        
        <TextInput 
          secureTextEntry
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          />     
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {  
    padding:20
  },
  input:{
    height:40,
    marginBottom:15,
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
    color:'#fff',
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  buttonContainer:{
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    paddingVertical:15
  },
  buttonText:{
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontWeight:'700'
  }

});
```

Code structure of application:

[image]

Comment: Add some code so we can evaluate better the reasons of issue.

Comment: code added have a look at it.

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for buil-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined . Check the render mehtod of `Login`.

Comment: try to put the Keyboard inside the View, i think you need the main View to be the first there but im not sure about this, just give it a try

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: maybe its the LoginForm?, show the LoginForm.js and maybe how the files are organized too

Comment: Ok let me share the LoginForm code

Comment: Which react native version are you using?

Comment: i try to run your code, but i don't find the error with your code in above when i build the code like [this](http://imgur.com/a/8EXIJ) .. Can you give me more clear about the error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';


export default class LoginForm extends Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state={
 username:'',
 password:''
 }
}
     login=()=>{
     alert('Username: ' + this.state.username + ' Password: ' + this.state.password );
     }
  render() {
    return (

      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" enabled>  
      <View style={styles.container}>              
        <TextInput             
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="username or email"
            onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          />        
        <TextInput 
          secureTextEntry
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          />     
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=>this.login()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {  
    flex:1
  },
  input:{
    height:40,
    marginBottom:15,
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)',
    color:'#fff',
    paddingHorizontal: 10
  },
  buttonContainer:{
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    paddingVertical:15
  },
  buttonText:{
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    fontWeight:'700'
  }

});
```

> Here is the working example

, You can copy and paste it. It will work
*If you want to connect it with back-end Rest-API*
**Use axios or fetch**

```
 fetch('http://{{YOUR IP ADDRESS OR IF GENYMOTION USE 10.0.3.2}}' ,{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json',
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        email:this.state.username,
        password:this.state.password,
      })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if(responseJson){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');        
        }else{
        alert("Sorry Wrong Credentials");
      }

      }).catch((error) =>{
          alert(error)
      })
```